# Serializing and deserializing enum with flag attribute using json

Tags: c#, json.net

I try to serialize my model object using JSON. I have no problem with doing this and I know how to deserialize it but in this case I don't get the result as I expected. I'll give my model class and also an example.

This is my class

```
public class ShortcutsModel
    {
        public string shortcutName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public ModifierKeys modifierKeys { get; set; }
        public Keys keys { get; set; }
    }
```

both ModifierKeys and Keys are enums and they both have flags attribute. ModifierKeys is custom and keys is the one inside Forms namespace. Anyway, I fill my object like this :

```
 ShortcutsModel scm = new ShortcutsModel();
 scm.shortcutName = "Load";
 cm.modifierKeys = Models.Enums.ModifierKeys.Control | Models.Enums.ModifierKeys.Alt;
 scm.keys = Keys.H | Keys.G;
```

without any problem, after that I serialize it like this in my properties's set :

```
string JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
```

I get the JSON string. It looks like this :

```
{"shortcutName":"Load","modifierKeys":3,"keys":79}
```

so far there is no problem. I save this value and want to get it back as I saved but when I deserialize it like this :

```
ShortcutsModel ReturningValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ShortcutsModel>(JSONString);
```

I don't get the same object as I serialized. After deserializing my class instance's keys property shows me Keys.O which is wrong because it was H+G when I serialized it.

I'm not sure why this is happening but I assume it's because my custom enum extends uint but the default Keys enum does not. Can someone provide me a way to deserialize my JSONString without this problem?

Thanks..

Comment: `scm.keys = Keys.H | Keys.G;` Please put a breakpoint on the line **after** that line. Run to the breakpoint. Go to the `Immediate Window`. Type in `?scm.keys`. What is the result? What does that tell you?

Comment: Never use `|` unless all flags are a power of 2, what is happening here is that G has value of 71, and H is 72, or-ing them gives 79, which is O

Comment: when I checked ?scm.keys in Immediate Windows I saw the letter 'O' which is weird I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that:

```
Keys.H | Keys.G
```

is equivalent to:

```
Keys.O
```

While `Keys` is a flags enum (and thus you can use `|`) you can only *really* use it with the [modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8) keys, such as:

> Shift 65536    The SHIFT modifier key.

So:

```
Keys.H | Keys.Shift
```

would be fine, but not:

```
Keys.H | Keys.G
```

*For your specific context, I'd recommend serialising an array of `Keys`.*

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I will be careful next time when I use FlagsAttribute :)

Comment: I've always considered this a bad use of the Flags attribute.  When I logically think of a flag, I think of it as mutually exclusive (i.e., bitmap, or powers of 2).  However, from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8): `Warning: Do not use the values in this enumeration for combined bitwise operations. The values in the enumeration are not mutually exclusive.`

Comment: @WonkotheSane It is confusing if you don't expect it, for sure.